# docker-compose error while trying to execute command on container: bash: groups: command not found

Tags: docker, docker-compose

After I executed:
`docker-compose up -d`
When I enter in the container and execute any bash cammand, this message apears:
"bash: groups: command not found"

obs.:
My OS is fedora 29,

Docker version `18.09.0, build 4d60db4`

docker-compose version `1.23.2, build 1110ad01`

dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04

WORKDIR /var/www/html

RUN apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt-get install -y \
 software-properties-common \
 python-software-properties \
 curl \
 build-essential \
 vim \
 sudo \
 whois \

# Install node and npm
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_9.x | sudo -E bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get update 

# Install apache
RUN apt-get install apache2 -y
RUN a2enmod rewrite


# Install PHP and modules
RUN apt-get install -y --force-yes \
 php7.2 \
 php-pear \
 php7.2-curl \
 php7.2-dev \
 php7.2-gd \
 php7.2-mbstring \ 
 php7.2-zip \
 php7.2-xml \
 php7.2-xdebug \
 php7.2-bcmath \
 php7.2-pgsql \
 php7.2-mysql

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# Config Apache
RUN echo "ServerName localhost" >> /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN sed -i '/<Directory \/>/,/<\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN sed -i '/<Directory \/usr\/share>/,/<\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
RUN sed -i '/<Directory \/var\/www\/>/,/<\/Directory>/ s/AllowOverride None/AllowOverride All/' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

# Config php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/^short_open_tag\s*=\s*Off/short_open_tag = On/g' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/^post_max_size\s*=\s*8M/post_max_size = 256M/g' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/^memory_limit\s*=\s*128M/memory_limit = 256M/g' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/^upload_max_filesize\s*=\s*2M/upload_max_filesize = 20M/g' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN echo "session.save_path = /tmp" >> /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/^serialize_precision\s*=\s*17/serialize_precision = 100/g' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/^display_startup_errors\s*=\s*Off/display_startup_errors = On/g' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/^session.gc_probability\s*=\s*0/session.gc_probability = 1/g' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/^session.bug_compat_42\s*=\s*Off/session.bug_compat_42 = On/g' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/^session.bug_compat_warn\s*=\s*Off/session.bug_compat_warn = On/g' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/^display_errors\s*=\s*Off/display_errors = On/g' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i '/error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED/c\error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/^;track_errors\s*=\s*Off/track_errors = On/g' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i 's/^html_errors\s*=\s*Off/html_errors = On/g' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini
RUN sed -i '/;error_log = php_errors.log/c\error_log = "\/var\/www\/logs\/php_error_log"' /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini

# Config xdebug
RUN echo "xdebug.remote_enable=1" >> /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini \
 && echo "xdebug.remote_autostart=1" >> /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini \
 && echo "xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1" >> /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini \
 && echo "xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1" >> /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini \
 && echo "xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1" >> /etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini

RUN chgrp -R www-data /var/www
RUN chmod -R 777 /var/www

EXPOSE 80 8080 631 8000 3000

CMD ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
```

docker compose:

```
version: "3"
services:
   php7:
    image: anapassos/php7
    container_name: php7
    volumes:
      - ./php7/www:/var/www/html      
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"
    environment:
      XDEBUG_CONFIG: remote_host=192.168.5.72
```

Comment: Please provide your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: I've updated the question with the dockerfile and docker-compose file

Comment: Does the binary actually exist?  Why would you need to call `groups` anyways?  Can you rip out 2/3 of this Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

I just removed the Group like David Maze suggested in the comments, in that worked for me. Thanks a lot!